ApacheSolr 9.6 Trying to Index the document Using SolrJ cleint I am getting the error
I am using Solr-core 9.6 jar and Apache Solr 9.6 version.
Simple Java method to index the document into the Apache solr 9.6
public void postData() throws SolrServerException, IOException {

        SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();

        // Add fields to the document
        document.addField("DEALER_ID", "1");
        document.addField("BILLING_CONTACT", "Nageshwar Chaganti");
        document.addField("DTNS", new String[] { "123", "456" });
        document.addField("REQ_LEADS_RADIUS", "10");
        document.addField("SALES_CONTACT", "Alice Johnson");
        document.addField("WEB_CITY", "Springfield");
        document.addField("WEB_STATE", "NY");
        document.addField("ZIP_CODE", "12345");
        SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://solrServer:8983/solr/<<corename>>")
                .build();

        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
        updateRequest.add(document);

        // Process the update request
        UpdateResponse response = updateRequest.process(solrClient);

        System.out.println("Document indexed successfully: " + response);

        System.out.println("Document indexed successfully: " + response);
    }
    

But same working with version Solr 4.x and 8.3 version

2024-09-02T10:59:19.791-04:00 ERROR 18832 --- [nio-9080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/solr9] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://solrserver:8983/solr/<>: Cannot parse provided JSON: JSON Parse Error: char=,position=0 AFTER='' BEFORE='��&params��&delByQ
